# How to adjust the TextView below corresponding to the ImageView?

Tags: android, xml, uiimageview, textview

I have used a `TableLayout` to hold three `ImageView` and their captions (`TextView`) just below the `ImageView`. Here in the second row as my `TextView` caption size increases my alignment of the image view changes. How to set it correctly. How can we split the `TextView` if it is long?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="11.5" >

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/btn_mypolicies"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/mypolicies" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:text="@string/mypolicies"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="6pt" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/btn_myclaims"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Iviewmyclaims"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:background="@drawable/myclaims" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/myclaims"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="6pt" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:id="@+id/btn_quick_quote"
             android:layout_weight="1" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/quickquote" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:text="@string/hme_quickquote"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="6pt" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

     </TableLayout>


 <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  

     <TableRow 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
         android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/btn_payonline"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/payonline" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pay_online"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="6pt" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/btn_claiminti"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" 
            >
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/claimintimation" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/claim_inti"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="6pt" 
         android:layout_weight="0.1"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/health_insurance"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/supportingnetworks" />

    <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
          android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
          android:text="@string/health_insurance_ntwk"
          android:textColor="@color/black"
          android:textSize="6pt"
          android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:ellipsize="end"` in your textview

Comment: with android:singleLine="true"?